# Nested loops don't modify

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for x in a:
   x[0] = 0

print(a)
```

gives:

```
[[0, 2, 3], [0, 5, 6], [0, 8, 9]]
```

but:

```
for x in a:
   for y in x:
       y = 0
```

gives:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I expected:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

Why couldn't I modify 'a' in the second example?

Comment: Not exactly, why does it work in the first case?

Comment: Because `y` is an `int`, which is immutable. `list` is a mutable object. You can change its contents

Comment: Ah, OK. I can change x but not y. 

Annoying. How can I (cleanly) modify all the values of a 2D list?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I'd argue that that distinction doesn't really exist in python.

Comment: `y = 0` You're rebinding the name `y` to a new value; it does not remember its previous life as the loop variable.

Comment: @dumbPotato21 While correct, this isn't the reason why `y` doesn't change. The reason is that `y` is a label pointing to each element in `x`, and `y = 0` just makes the label to point to `0` instead.

Comment: True. Doing `x = [0,0,0]` wouldn't work either. Just wanted to mention that you can change a list. Changing ints is not possible

Comment: OK, so x is a label for the sub list on a, and if I change the first element of that label=, I change the actual list? I think I get that.

Comment: @TimMottram You do  `for x in a: for i in range(len(x)): x[i] = 0` to modify all elements.

Comment: You simply set a variable ```y``` to a value of ```0``` instead of referencing to the index of the inner list.

You are iterating in a manner that results with the actual elements inside a list. However, if your aim is to change the values of the list, iterating over the indexes (as you are doing in your first example: ```for x in a:
   x[0] = 0```), would do the trick (at least for the last iteration).

Comment: @TimMottram yes. whenever you do `x = something` in python, you're binding `x` to a new object. It doesn't change the original value.

Comment: Just a note:

```for x in a: for i in range(len(x)): x[i] = 0```

Gave me a syntax error...